RandomForest project
I am very new and fresh to machine learning and this is my first project I am working on as part of a college course. I chose UK football (soccer) matches. I have chosen to use a Random Forest.
Using different sources I have managed to get 20 years worth of data on said matches, clean the data and build my model.
However, I am stuck. How do I actually get the model to make predictions for future matches?
Thanks
I've tried to load the model and then use a CSV file with only the Date, Home_Team and Away_Team columns populated, leaving the other columns blank for the model to predict these values - is this the correct way to do this?
Update:
Thanks - please see the code used to build the model;
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
train = matches[matches["Date"] < '2012-06-01']
test = matches[matches["Date"] > '2012-06-01']
predictors = ['Home_Team', 'Away_Team',     'HT_Winner', 'FT_Winner', 'match_result', 'ht_match_result',     'HomeShots',     'AwayShots', 'HomeCorners', 'AwayCorners']
rf.fit(train[predictors], train["FT_Winner"])
preds = rf.predict(test[predictors])

New CSV for future predictions:
import pandas as pd

new_data_df = pd.read_csv(..)
predictions = model.predict(new_data_df)

Updated CSV contains all of the same columns (with only Date, Home_Team and Away_Team columns populated as this is the only info currently available and the other columns wanting the model to make predictions for. But when attempting to get predictions for the new CSV, I get the following;
"Feature names must be in the same order as they were in fit.\n"
ValueError(message)
ValueError: The feature names should match those that were passed during fit.


You have to add (minimal) code and show what you have tried so that we can get the context. Also there is no mention of what library are you using.

First you need to decide what are you trying to predict. Let's say the prediction variable in your case is the winning team based.
Now, you pick up the important variable which you think would be related to your output, and you call them X. In random forest, you provide both X, y at training time to make your model learn the parameters. Later for prediction, you take some test samples and only provide X, and your model returns the predicted output, you compare it with their original output and use some scoring metric to see how good your model performs.

Thanks - please see the code used to build the model;
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
train = matches[matches["Date"] < '2012-06-01']
test = matches[matches["Date"] > '2012-06-01']
predictors = ['Home_Team', 'Away_Team', 'HT_Winner', 'FT_Winner', 'match_result', 'ht_match_result', 'HomeShots', 'AwayShots', 'HomeCorners', 'AwayCorners']
rf.fit(train[predictors], train["FT_Winner"])
preds = rf.predict(test[predictors])
New CSV for future predictions:
import pandas as pd
new_data_df = pd.read_csv(..)
predictions = model.predict(new_data_df)
Hope this helps

can you edit the question and add the code there properly?
Thanks

Your input variable (X) should be the same in both training and testing. Remember, your model trys to learn the mapping of input to the output. In your case, all the predictors are input and the 'FT_Winner' is your target variable y. So, try to provide the same input variables for test too (in your case its your predictor list).

Sorry, new to SO -- updated the main body now accordingly.

also, can you share where are you getting stuck? because if your new df data (prediction one) contains the ft_winner variable, and you pass the new_data_df without removing the ft_winner variable, it should throw you an error.

I've added to the main body some further details on what I am attempting to do (rightly or wrongly....) and the error it is coming back with

Your issue is related to the parameters you are passing. Your input parameters is the predictors list that you have provided in the code above.
When you read the new csv file for future predictions, make sure that csv has all the columns which are in predictors list and select those columns
so if the new_data_df has all the predictors, you can use the following line for prediction.
predictions = model.predict(new_data_df[predictors])

Amazing, thank you so much. I've managed to run the model successfully following your steps. Thanks again!

Your issue is your about the input features. You are using the predictor list as list of features for training.
For testing, you still need the same input list in your new_data_df. If the new_data_df has all of the predictors column, you can use the following to line of code for predictions
predictions = model.predict(new_data_df[predictors])

Just remember, for prediction, you always need to pass all the parameters you passed during training apart from the target or result column.
